# AWK and regular patterns

Tags: awk

I have a sequence, for example:

```
>sequence.fasta
GATCCAAAACACATTCTCCCTGGTAGCATGGACAAGCAACATTTTGGGAGAAATGGAGCAAAAAAACATA
AACTTCACAGTAACAAACATAAACACTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTC
TCTCTCTCCACACACACACACACTCGCACTCACAGCCTCACAACACAGGTATACATGTTTACTTAGGTCA
CTCAGAATTGTAAACTGTAAGTGTGCCTTGCAAAGAACCACTGCTCCTTACAGTGAGCAGTGCTTACCTG
```

and with this code:

```
awk '{if (NR!=1) {printf $0}}' sequence.fasta | awk '{sub(/ATG/, "\n&")}1' | awk 'NR==2' | fold -w 60 | awk '{gsub(/.../,"& ")}1'
```

I produce this output (an example):

```
ATG TTA ACT TTT ACA TGT TAC CTT TTG ATG TGT GAT GAG AAG ATG ACG ACT CAT TAG AAT 
GCT TTT TAG GCA ATC TTC AAG AGT ATT TTA CTA CTT TTG AAA ATA AAT AAA TAA ATT CAA 
ATT TTA TTC TTA AAA ATC TAT AAT TTT TTG TAT TAA CCA AAC TTA AAT ATC CAA GTA AGG 
GCT GTT AGA TAA GAT AGG TGA TAT TTC TCA AGT AGA TTT ACA TTT TAT AAT GCT CTC CAA 
ATG ATC TTA ATG GTT AAA TCT AAG TTT TTA TTC TTA CCT GTA TGA AAA TAC AAA GTT TAT
```

I'd like to find "TAA", "TGA" or "TAG", and have an output from first element (ATG) to "TAA, "TGA" or "TAG"... The desired output:

```
ATG TTA ACT TTT ACA TGT TAC CTT TTG ATG TGT GAT GAG AAG ATG TGA
```

Comment: If you give an example of your `sequence.fasta` we could try to find a unique call to `awk` to perform all this code, as you are piping to way way many times.

Comment: What does `have an output from first element (ATG) to "TAA, "TGA" or "TAG"` mean? Show your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?  It search for any of `TAA TGA TAG` and print the first column of line if hit.

```
awk '/TAA|TGA|TAG/ {print $1}'
ATG
GCT
ATT
GCT
ATG
TCA
ATA
TAT
TGA
```

Comment: So you only wants the six first field if what?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself using this code:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {printf $i" "; if ($i~/TAA/ || $i~/TAG/ || $i~/TGA/) {exit}}}'
```