# HowTo. Writing an awk script

Tags: awk, pipe

Good afternoon from Spain. I am learning AWK and I know how to do commands from Linux terminal using pipes, but I'd like to be able to write AWK scripts. Let's see if you can help me.

I have the following code:

```
awk '{if (NR!=1) {printf $0}}' sequence.fasta |
awk '{sub(/ATG/, "\n&")}{print}' |
awk 'NR == 2' | awk '{gsub(/.../, "& ")}1' |
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {printf $i" "; if ($i~/TAA/ || $i~/TAG/ || $i~/TGA/) {exit}}}' |
fold -w 60
```

From a FASTA file, this script shows from START codon (ATG) to STOP codon (TAA, TAG or TGA). A FASTA file have the following structure:

```
>sequence.fasta
GATCCAAAACACATTCTCCCTGGTAGCATGGACAAGCAACATTTTGGGAGAAATGGAGCAAAAAAACATA
AACTTCACAGTAACAAACATAAACACTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTC
TCTCTCTCCACACACACACACACTCGCACTCACAGCCTCACAACACAGGTATACATGTTTACTTAGGTCA
CTCAGAATTGTAAACTGTAAGTGTGCCTTGCAAAGAACCACTGCTCCTTACAGTGAGCAGTGCTTACCTG
GTGCTTACCTGAAGAAGATATAGCTCCTTAAAGAGTAAATGAATAAATACCTTAAGTAAGTTTGGGAAAC
```

Applying the code I've written above, I obtain the following output:

```
ATG GAC AAG CAA CAT TTT GGG AGA AAT GGA GCA AAA AAA CAT AAA 
CTT CAC AGT AAC AAA CAT AAA CAC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT 
CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CCA CAC ACA CAC ACA 
CTC GCA CTC ACA GCC TCA CAA CAC AGG TAT ACA TGT TTA CTT AGG 
TCA CTC AGA ATT GTA AAC TGT AAG TGT GCC TTG CAA AGA ACC ACT 
GCT CCT TAC AGT GAG CAG TGC TTA CCT GGT GCT TAC CTG AAG AAG 
ATA TAG
```

So, my code do it:

It prints all sequence together except header. Printf prints without \n.

```
awk '{if (NR!=1) {printf $0}}' sequence.fasta
```

It looks for first ATG and introduces a new line.

```
awk '{sub(/ATG/, "\n&")}{print}'
```

As we have just introduces a new line when ATG starts, se select line 2, ignoring line 1 (5'-UTR).

```
awk 'NR == 2'
```

Now, we create codons, separated by a space.

```
awk '{gsub(/.../, "& ")}1'
```

Now, with a loop, we are looking for a STOP codon. When finds it, the loop stops.

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {printf $i" "; if ($i~/TAA/ || $i~/TAG/ || $i~/TGA/) {exit}}}'
```

For better view, we fix 60 characters the width.

```
fold -w 60
```

So, I've tried to put all together in a `script.awk`, but it doesn't work. I know that with awk it is not as simple as writing all together. So, might you help me with it, please?

Comment: It is absolutely `as simple as writing it all together`, but you need to know what `it all` is supposed to do. Why does your expected output start with `ATG GAC` when the first occurrence of `ATG` in your input is followed by `AAG` as far as I can see. And don't start talking about fastas and codones or whatever that stuff means inyour domain - just talk about the patterns/combinations of letters/strings in your input text.

Comment: It was just an example. My output goes from first occurrence ATG to first codon stop.

Comment: When posting an example, it helps us to help you if we can match the input to the output so please edit your question to post input and the corresponding output, not 2 disparate sets. And you should not expect any of the awk experts reading this to know or care what a "codon stip" is - just say `I want to find the first occurrence of "FOOBAR"`or whatever string or strings you're looking for.

Comment: In my opinion, I've said what is exactly every thing I've written. I think you are over-reacting.

Comment: @user2886545 He is not over reacting. **Input shown here doesn't give shown output with shown code** [**`This is your previous post`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19857412/awk-and-regular-patterns). There question was so unclear that I had waste time solving problem for improper output. And here you go again

Comment: You understand nothing. My previous post was a question that I've solved by myself because nobody gave a correct answer. NOW is another question (with my previous questions solved). IT IS NOT THE SAME QUESTION.

Comment: @user2886545 Yeah we understand nothing. Then why do you bother to post question here? We all are dumb here. *Nobody gave a correct ans? Really?* You show folded input there and expect desired output? I didn't say it's the same post. I said **inputs and outputs are unclear**.

Comment: @user2886545 you have posted lots of question regarding same project, over and over again. We are here to help, not to make a complete solution for you!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Don't make me laugh. This post has unclear inputs and outputs?

Comment: @user2886545 - you're being rude and foolish. Think about what you're doing. Do you really think the reason no-one gave the answer you wanted is because we are incapable of solving your problem or because you haven't phrased your problem in a coherent way as we're telling you is the case?

Comment: @user2886545 you solved it by yourself? Really? [**`Then what's this?`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859080/break-in-awk-doesnt-work). You think we are so much fool??

Comment: My problem is perfectly explained.

Comment: @jkshah You mean just changing "break" for "exit"?

Comment: @user2886545 I mean nothing. As you said, I don't understand anything and very stupid that I'm arguing here. I quit. Sorry to bother you!

Comment: @user2886545 - in your mind you have the context for each question you post along with domain knowledge, and the understanding of the related terminology. I'm sure you can read one of your questions and it's perfectly clear. To the rest of us, though, each question is just a pile of mismatched input/output and a bunch of meaningless phrases with no clear mapping or direction on what you're trying to do. Also, each solution you get to a specific question is wrong because your whole approach is wrong. Whatever it is you're trying to do end-to-end can, I'm sure, be solved by a single awk script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all you're trying to do is skip the first line then print from the first occurrence of "ATG" in your file to the first occurrence of TAA, TGA, or TAG in combinations of 3 letters and print them out in rows of 15 columns. If so, that's simply this:

```
$ cat file
>whatever
GATCCAAAACACATTCTCCCTGGTAGCATGGACAAGCAACATTTTGGGAGAAATGGAGCAAAAAAACATA
AACTTCACAGTAACAAACATAAACACTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTC
TCTCTCTCCACACACACACACACTCGCACTCACAGCCTCACAACACAGGTATACATGTTTACTTAGGTCA
CTCAGAATTGTAAACTGTAAGTGTGCCTTGCAAAGAACCACTGCTCCTTACAGTGAGCAGTGCTTACCTG
GTGCTTACCTGAAGAAGATATAGCTCCTTAAAGAGTAAATGAATAAATACCTTAAGTAAGTTTGGGAAAC
$
$ cat tst.awk
NR>1 { rec = rec $0 }
END {
    if ( match(rec,/ATG/) ) {
        rec = substr(rec,RSTART)
        gsub(/.../,"& ",rec)
        match(rec,/(TAA|TAG|TGA) /)
        rec = substr(rec,1,RSTART+RLENGTH-2)
        gsub(/(... ){15}/,"&\n",rec)
        print rec
    }
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
ATG GAC AAG CAA CAT TTT GGG AGA AAT GGA GCA AAA AAA CAT AAA
CTT CAC AGT AAC AAA CAT AAA CAC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT
CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CTC TCT CCA CAC ACA CAC ACA
CTC GCA CTC ACA GCC TCA CAA CAC AGG TAT ACA TGT TTA CTT AGG
TCA CTC AGA ATT GTA AAC TGT AAG TGT GCC TTG CAA AGA ACC ACT
GCT CCT TAC AGT GAG CAG TGC TTA CCT GGT GCT TAC CTG AAG AAG
ATA TAG
$
```

Comment: I really appreciate it. Thank you very much, Ed.

Comment: No problem. As soon as you updated your input to match your output it was easy enough to see what you wanted.

Comment: Just as a comment. A FAST file has a sequence, but the sequence starts from line 2. Line 1 is always a header where the sequence is defined (name, code and definition). For this reason, I've done `awk '{if (NR!=1) {printf $0}}' sequence.fasta` with individual commands.

Comment: Your posted input didn't show a first line that had to be skipped. Again, don't expect anyone to know what a FASTA file is or condones or whatever the heck your terminology is - just post representative input, expected output, and explain the mapping in terms of the text not what the text means. Oh, I see that line that starts with `>` really is part of your input, I thought it was a mistake. I've updated my answer.